# How to autoupload a file to an FTP server on save in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ftp

I'm trying to automatically upload a file to an FTP server when I save the file in Eclipse, How do I do that?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-plugin-ftp-server/ this may help you

Comment: How do I install this in eclipse? I get the jar, I already put it in the plugins folder, I open eclipse, How do i setup my server configuration?